# Count the number of times a variable's value is added

Tags: java

So the question asks me to do the following:

```
public boolean addRating(int rating)
```

> Add a rating for the video. If rating is between 1-5 inclusive, then
>   update the ratings for this video, keeping track of how many ratings
>   for it have been received, and return true. Otherwise, print out an
>   error message and return false.

And this is what I managed to do:

```
   public class Video {

    private int rating;

    public boolean addRating(int rating){
        this.rating = rating;
        boolean result;
        int newRating = rating;
        if(newRating>=1 && newRating <=5){
            rating = newRating;
            result = true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

So my question is how exactly do I count the number of times a video is rated?

Comment: You don't need the variable `newRating`, you already have `rating` to compare 1..5.

Comment: What ideas have you thought of so far? Are there any existing data structures that map a key or a number (like a rating) to an object (like a number of ratings)? Do you need a single rating count, or more than one?

Comment: This really depends on the scope of the Video class

Comment: @Sotirios But then how am I going to update the rating? (rating = rating obviously doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to state that you need to remember multiple ratings for one video.  Notice that the method name is `addRating` not `setRating`.  You better model this with a list of ratings:

```
List<Integer> ratings;
```

Then tracking the number of ratings is as simple as computing the size of the list.  Your call might look like this:

```
public class Video {
    private List<Integer> ratings = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public boolean addRating(int rating){

        // Some other code you will have to write...

        ratings.add(rating);

        // Some other code you will have to write...

    }
}
```

Comment: But the argument of the method has already been given to us i.e. "int rating".

Comment: @ManasBajaj That is the argument to the method, but that doesn't control what you store.  To be clear, I meant that in your class you should have `private List<Integer> ratings;`.  Then when addRating is called with an int, you can do ratings.add(rating);

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

```
public class Video {

  private int rating = 0;  // sum of all ratings
  private int count = 0;  // count the number of ratings

  public boolean addRating(int newRating){

      boolean result;
      if(newRating>=1 && newRating <=5){
          count++;
          this.rating = this.rating + newRating;
          result = true;
      }
      else{
          System.out.println("ERROR!");
          result = false;
      }
      return result;
  }

  // returns the avg of the ratings added
  public int getRating(){

      return Math.Round(((double) rating) / ((double) count));  
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! That seems like an awesome approach. Thanks : )

Comment: @ManasBajaj I found it a better approach than the `private List<Integer> ratings` because all you need is to know the average of the votes. By using a List you are saving all the votes, but when returning your rating you will have to sum all the votes and divide by the size of the List and that will take more memory and processing time that you don't need to waste.